# Python: Read the file and output the three biggest numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

The file numbers.txt contains random integer numbers. There is exactly one number per line. Read the file and output the three biggest numbers in the following form:

```
2345
223
89
```

Hint:

Read the file line by line, delete the line break. As files can only contain strings, the number must now be converted into an integer. Add the number into a list. When all numbers are in the list, sort the list. Then print out the biggest numbers.

Comment: The "hint" lays out exactly how to do it, word for word.  What problem are you running into?

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem. Typically the teacher will specify the language to use. So narrow it down to *either* Python 2 or 3, though the solution won't vary much between Python versions.

Comment: Write code and if you have a problem, post the code and a description of the problem. Then we can try our luck with it.

Comment: please answer it in python 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

print(*sorted((int(n.strip()) for n in open("numbers.txt")), reverse=True)[:3], sep="\n")

This solution worked..!